# Having difficulty placing an array of numbers into a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm getting a better understanding of functions, arrays and for loops. I'm looking to create a function which takes in an array of numbers and returns the total of all the items in the array added together. I figured out how to total an array.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var myTotal = 0;

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     myTotal += myArray[i];
}
                                   
console.log (myTotal);
```

I know how to create/call a function, however when I attempt to add the two concepts together it never works. Are you able to place an array into the parameters of a function?

More or less I want to create a code concept which takes on an array of numbers into a function which totals the array. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks for taking the time to read my long winded question.

Comment: did you declared var i before using it ?

Comment: *"when I attempt to add the two concepts together it never works"* Show that attempt, then we can tell you what's not quite right.

Comment: Side note: You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): Declare `i`.

Comment: Seeing what you have tried would help here. Yes, you can pass arrays into functions, just like any other value. `myFunc([1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: Thanks guys, trust when I state I appreciate all the help. Again, I'm new to code and Stack Overflow. I'm amazed at the speed of response. 

Zoe - I believe so inside the for loop.
T.J. Crowder - Thanks for the resource. I'll make certain to read this today.
deceze - Thanks, I figured as much, but I believe my syntax is off. I'm going to read the other responses, do some additional work and will edit my post afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Any value, including an array reference, can be passed into a function.

Here's what's needed in your case:

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function totalArray(arr) {
  var myTotal = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     myTotal += arr[i];
  }

  return myTotal;
}

document.getElementById("value").innerText = totalArray(myArray);
```

```html
<div id="value"></div>
```

Comment: Really not trying to give you a hard time here, but the statement *"in javascript, everything is an object."* is just incorrect. JavaScript has primitives, which are not objects, and in fact the `3` in your `var a=3` is an example of a primitive. JS is indeed **very** object-oriented, more so even than many other OOP languages, but *everything* is not an object.

Comment: Fair point, I'm more than happy to accept an edit. I'm pretty new to the forum business so will take the learning experiences and corrections as they arise

Comment: On an interesting side note. I can say `var a = 3`, then call `a.toString()` which returns `"3"`. This implies some degree of functionality beyond the pure primitive

Comment: The `a.toString()` thing happens because the number primitive `3` is temporarily promoted to a `Number` object, which inherits from `Number.prototype` and so has `toString`. Number primitives *aren't* `Number` objects (`3 === new Number(3)` is `false`), but some expressions (like property accesses on them) temporarily coerce them into `Number` objects.

Comment: That's a lesson learned for me today. Thanks for that, and the edit.

Comment: No worries, it's one of the more interesting parts of JS. You may find this interesting (or not :-) ): https://jsfiddle.net/jf8cd7bw/

Comment: Excellent demonstration, pity for others it is hidden so far in the comments

Comment: Don't worry, there's a question and answer about it somewhere here; I should have just found it and given you that link instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function totalArray(arr) {
    var myTotal = 0;
    arr.forEach(number){myTotal +=number};
return myTotal;
}

console.log(totalArray(myArray));
```

Instead of a for loop you can also use for Each as shown above.

//btw I guess the mistake was just expecting the code to run instead of telling it to run.

Javascript has its problems put every functionality in a function then execute it, is the normal way of doing things.
While the snipet might run here, some things are needed in actual code for it to run

Comment: Thanks @Gammeldags for the response and feedback. I'm unfamiliar with .forEach, but will look into this for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a,b){return a + b;});
}

console.log(sum(myArray));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
See if this helps :
//function 
function getTotal(myArray){

var myTotal = 0;

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     myTotal += myArray[i];
}

 return  myTotal;
}


//function call
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var total = getTotal(myArray);
```

console.log(total);

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ganpat Jha!